# Methods for generating 'random' codes for use with physical/offline verification? PHP/WEB

Tags: php, web, offline

Long story short, I want to create an automated gift certificate system. I have decided that since the authentication system is largely manual (scan qrcode/input qc code), there is little chance for bruteforce. (I am sure after the hundredth try, we'd just kick the dude out.)

As such, the gift code will be a mix of a sequential GC(Gift Code) ID. And some sort of hash/code unique to that sequential ID. IE. CODE_1001 // SHA1HASHBLAHBLAH.

This allows for a human (ie. server) readable code to match with a unique tag for verification.

Specifically, I am wondering what the best practice might be in this case.

Do I generate a totally random code in a large space and assume there will be no collision between the pair of GCID and UniID? Or somehow salt the generated code with the sequential key?

Comment: What's the problem with generating a totally random code?

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php would be my try, I've used this function a lot to generate unique values without collision.

or use: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php

Answer (score 0):

This may help.

```
    $var = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($var['value']));
    or
    $var = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($var));
    or
    $var = mysql_real_escape_string(sha512($var['value']));
    or
    $var = mysql_real_escape_string(sha512($var));
```

Comment: The `mysql_real_escape_string()` function does not add any advantage, actually one should call it only to prepare text for using inside an SQL statement. Since the output of the hash functions have a well defined alphabet anyway, it just makes no sense.